Sci-Fi movie with a dome and cannibalism
My husband just asked me about a movie and I had no idea what he was talking about. He had no idea when the movie came out and he's not sure about anyone in the cast...he said it could have been Emilio Estevez or Bill Pullman (and I did check IMDB, but nothing stood out)
What he could remember...a house appears in the middle of a field under a dome that blocks the people inside the house from seeing anything outside the dome and no one can pass through it. But it's discovered that every once in a while the dome is penetrable, so the military set up at the dome and start shooting ice cubes at the dome until they start to pass through. Then Emilio/Bill/????? runs towards the house and the dome goes back up. When he turns around he can no longer see the military, all he sees is an open field. Then the people from the house come out and eat him. 
Does ANYONE know this movie?

Why is this a duplicate? The questions aren't close. Is it really the same movie? The OP is probably not coming back after only getting DUPLICATE as a response.

Walt's answer needs to be undeleted. This is almost certainly a dupe though; https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/12635/100979
